# Accessing Unity particle emitter via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a particle system created, and in a certain point in my game I would like to increase the max particles.

As a result, I created a game object and attached a box 2d collider to it that fires when it comes in contact with the player. In that script, I have created a public GameObject leafParticleSystem, and dragged the particle system into it.

However, in my code, I am unable to do anything like

```
leafParticleSystem.maxParticles=500;
```

or

```
leafParticleSystem.emission.rate=5.0f
```

My code is also saying

```
"MissingComponentException: There is no 'ParticleSystem' attached to the "Herld" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a ParticleSystem to the game object "Herld". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.untime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)"
```

However, this "Herld" GameObject is not the particle system (nor do I want to add one to it) It however, does have the script attached which I am dragging the particle system (leaf particle system) to. I am just trying to modify the leaf particle system from my code in the "Herld" object.

Would appreciate if I could get any assistance

Script Attached

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class WindEffect : MonoBehaviour {
//  Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
    // Use this for initialization

    //Storm Warning
    public GameObject AOE;
    public GameObject UIStormInterface;
    public GameObject UIWindZone;

    public GameObject LeafStormParticleSystem;


    public float ActivateFor=5.0f;
    public float stormLength=5.0f; 


    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void Awake () {

//      _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
    // Debug.Log("Object touched trigger");
    //  Debug.Log (col.transform.name); 
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Player") {
            Debug.Log ("Collided with Storm Herald");
            StartCoroutine (TemporarilyActivateStormWarning (ActivateFor));

        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TemporarilyActivateStormWarning(float ActivateFor) {
    //Show Storm Warning
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled=(false);
        UIStormInterface.GetComponent<Text>().text="A Violent Storm is Approaching";
        UIStormInterface.SetActive(true);

        UIWindZone.SetActive (true);
        //Wait for 5 seconds then activate storm for 5 seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(ActivateFor);

        UIStormInterface.SetActive(false);
        AOE.SetActive (true);

        //  ParticleSystem LeafStormParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    //  LeafStormParticleSystem.emission.rate = 5.0f;
        LeafStormParticleSystem.maxParticles = 500;


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(stormLength);


        //Turn off Storm
        AOE.SetActive (false);
        //Tell user storm is stopped for 2 seconds.

        UIStormInterface.GetComponent<Text>().text="Storm has Passed";
        UIStormInterface.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        UIStormInterface.SetActive(false);
        UIWindZone.SetActive (false);
    }
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "WindObject") {
            Debug.Log ("Collided");
            //  Debug.Log (col.transform.name); 
        //  Wind();
            //StartCoroutine(WindStart());
        }
    }
    /*
    IEnumerator WindStart(){
        Debug.LogError ("Slow Time.");

        //SlowTheTime();
    //  yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.5f);
        //  Debug.LogError ("Slow Time.");
    //  Wind ();
    }*/


    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
//      Debug.Log (col.transform.name); 
    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        Debug.Log("Object is in trigger");

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Object left the trigger");
    }


    /*
    void Wind(){
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        Debug.Log ("test got here");
        Debug.Log (this.gameObject.name);
        this._rigidbody.AddForce (-Vector2.left * 100 );
    }*/

}
```

Comment: Can you include the script attached to the "Herld" GameObject? And is `leafParticleSystem` a reference to it?

Comment: Script included, yes it is, I dragged it and dropped it in the public game object as I did all the other public variables i used to access scores and the canvas etc

Comment: Thanks. So let me see if I understand the situation...`leafParticleSystem` is a public GameObject variable, onto which you dragged the GameObject "Herld" (which has the `WindEffect` component attached)? And the particle system you want to access is stored in the public variable `LeafStormParticleSystem` of the `WindEffect` script?

Comment: No, leafParticleSystem is the public GameObject variable on to which i dragged the Particle Object from the heirachy. 
and Yes, the GameObject Herald DOES have the windEffect component attached, and yes, the particles I want to edit is that LeafStormParticleSystem

Comment: Uh...hm, so is `leafParticleSystem` the GameObject with the particle system on it, or is it `LeafStormParticleSystem`? I'm having trouble visualizing the relationship based on your last comment.

Comment: Yes, LeafStormParticleSystem is the public GameObject with the Particle System dragged on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently, your `LeafStormParticleSystem` variable gives you a reference to the GameObject that the `ParticleSystem` component is on, but not the `ParticleSystem` itself. As a result, you can't access members of the particle system like `maxParticles` and `emission`. There are two approaches you can take to correct this:

**Call `GetComponent<ParticleSystem>()` when you need access to the particle system.** This can be costly if done too often - syntax to modify members would be:

```cs
LeafStormParticleSystem.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().maxParticles = 500;
```

**Change your `LeafStormParticleSystem` from a `GameObject` to a `ParticleSystem`.** This lets you assign to `LeafStormParticleSystem` a direct reference to the particle system in the editor, and is more efficient than calling `GetComponent()` repeatedly. Syntax would be:

```cs
// Change the datatype
public ParticleSystem LeafStormParticleSystem;

// [...]
// To modify members later, you can do as you're currently doing:
LeafStormParticleSystem.maxParticles = 500;

// Modifying the emission rate is a bit less straightforward, because emission is a struct
var newEmission = LeafStormParticleSystem.emission;
newEmission.rate = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve(5.0f);
LeafStormParticleSystem.emission = newEmission;
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Great, that's it thanks. 
Final thing, Im still getting and error when i say :  LeafStormParticleSystem.emission.rate=40.0f;

Comment: @UnknownCode Interesting, perhaps you're trying to modify a struct? What's the error say?

Comment: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.ParticleSystem.emission'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable
Property or indexer `UnityEngine.ParticleSystem.emission' cannot be assigned to (it is read only)
Don't get why it would be read only

Comment: @UnknownCode That's because `emission` is a struct, which are immutable here. You need to get a copy of the value, modify its `rate` variable, then assign it back to `emission` - I've edited the answer accordingly. Let me know if it works alright!

Comment: Emission has a min and max value thou.

Comment: @UnknownCode Updated answer to create a new `ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve` for the rate. If you need it to have a min and max value (as opposed to the code you currently have), use the constructor that takes two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: now I see your script and...yes..you don't have a reference to the ParticleSystem

Here you do not access the ParticleSystem object, you access the GameObject that contains it:
LeafStormParticleSystem.maxParticles = 500;

make a reference to the ParticleSystem itself, not the GameObject.

```
LeafStormParticleSystem.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().maxParticles = 500;
```

OLD:
you should get a reference to your particle system (in my case I stop it) for example in Start function:

```
private ParticleSystem ps;
void Start()
{
    ps = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>();
    ps.Stop();
}
```

After that you can start or edit the particles (in my case in a separate function for play and change maxParticles):

```
void StartEmission()
{
    ps.Play();
    ps.maxParticles = 500;
}
```

Comment: if you have the reference as in my Start function do it like this:
LeafStormParticleSystem.emissionRate = 32;

if you do not have the reference as in my Start function (just the GameObject) do it like this:
LeafStormParticleSystem.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().emissionRate = 32;

Comment: In Unity 5.5.0f3 (mine) emissionRate parameter is obsolete but still working.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Just try to change the datatype of LeafStormParticleSystem to ParticleSystem.
So that you can access the methods and attributes related with particle system with the help of LeafStormParticleSystem variable

```
public ParticleSystem LeafStormParticleSystem;
```

**Solution 2:**

You can't directly access ParticleSystem methods and attributes of a GameObject unless and until you are not typecast that variable to ParticleSystem type.

For that you can try:

```
LeafStormParticleSystem.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().maxParticles = 500;
```

or

```
((ParticleSystem)LeafStormParticleSystem).maxParticles = 500;
```